# Can we send Firebase ServerValue timestamp in a notification?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging

I would like to know if it is possible to send the Firebase ServerValue timestamp inside an FCM notification sent via the REST API. I know that these values are auto populated inside the real time database when it arrives, does the same happen when sent via the FCM send API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to get a server-side timestamp injected into FCM messages. You will have to pass in a value from your own client/the app server that sends the message.

You can estimate the value that the Firebase Database would use by listening for the clock-skew of your client/app server. The [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/offline-capabilities#clock-skew) has this example of that:

> ```
> var offsetRef = firebase.database().ref(".info/serverTimeOffset");
> offsetRef.on("value", function(snap) {
>   var offset = snap.val();
>   var estimatedServerTimeMs = new Date().getTime() + offset;
> });
> ```

Comment: Thank you... I figured as much... Going to call the REST API of db and insert a .sv value at a node and receive the timestamp as the response :) will send this along now... Mate @Frank van Puffelen , could you share your contact email or something... You seem to be the go to guy for firebase and I'm in over my head developing a startup.... If it's ok i can ping in case i am stuck and pick your brain :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can please check below code and see how i added timestamp in data object

```
{
    "to" : "sdfdfssde1w6hEbZn-8:APAb2JewYCIiApsMu5JfI5Ak...",
    "notification": {
        "body": "This is test msg",
        "title": "title here",
        "icon": "appicon"
    },
    "data" : {
     "name" : "lenovo k4",
     "product_id" : "122",
     "final_price" : "12500",
     "timestamp" : "1483095084"
   }
}
```

Comment: How did you get the value for the timestamp? How did you set that value is my question ... Can you please post the code?

Answer (score 0):

The current server timestamp can be obtained using the now() method of firebase 'Timestamp'. [ref](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Timestamp#static-now)

```
const currentTimestamp = firebase.firestore.Timestamp.now(); //firebase timestamp format
```

Then pass this value to the data section of the FCM, as a key-value pair.